# Behat CSS selector - Finding by class can only be done with the first class

Tags: traversal, behat

**Scenario**

Say you have an input field with multiple CSS classes, such as:

```
<input class="form-control existing-user" value="Darth Darth Binks"/>
```

And in the behat step you want to find its value by finding the input element by CSS class.

**This works**

```
$field = $this->getPage()->findAllBy('css', 'form-control')[0]->getValue();
// $field is now "Darth Darth Binks"
```

**This does NOT work**

```
$field = $this->getPage()->findAll('css', 'existing-user')[0]->getValue();
// $field is now null
```

**Question**

What is the difference here? Do I need to do something specific if I look for one of the classes that are NOT written first?

Comment: [Iterate div elements with same class name to get their contents](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/vsok/iterate-div-elements-with-same-class-name-to-get-their-contents), [Click on an element that has an ID tag with CSS selector](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/2y0l/click-on-an-element-that-has-an-id-tag-with-css-selector), [Get the content of given element with ID](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/97ju/get-the-content-of-given-element-with-id), [Click on an element that has an ID tag](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/pzxm/click-on-an-element-that-has-an-id-tag)

Answer (score 1):

In both examples you should use a valid css selector, for class you should use a '.' in front of the class.
Some valid css selectors for the provided input element are:

```css
input.form-control
input.existing-user
input.form-control.existing-user
```

So a valid use would be:

```
$field = $this->getPage()->findAll('css', '.existing-user')->getValue();
```

Also please please keep in mind that findAll method would not throw exception if the element is not found, instead will return null and using get value on a null will result in php fatal error.
Implement exception handling and use/implement an waitForElement method if needed.